# Request reroute in Go, map HandleFuncs

Tags: go, gorequest

I want to map path names to files that live at a different location. But my code serves `/path/c.txt` when I visit `/a`, instead of `/path/a.txt`. What am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fileRoutes := map[string]string {
        "/a": "/path/a.txt",
        "/b": "/path/b.txt",
        "/c": "/path/c.txt",
    }

    for req, path := range fileRoutes {
        http.HandleFunc(req, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Printf("actual request: %v\n", r.URL.Path)
            fmt.Printf("registered request: %v\n", req)

            r.URL.Path = path

            fmt.Println(req)
            fmt.Println(path)

            // serveFile(w, r)
        })
    }

    http.ListenAndServe(":8004", nil)
}
```

This sample code produces:

```
actual request: /a
registered request: /c
/c
/path/c.txt
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all the handle functions are accessing the same `req` and `path` that is set to the last variable of the loop after the loop, which are `/c` and `/path/c.txt`.

To fix the problem, add `req,path := req,path` before `http.HandleFunc(...)`.

It seems weird. What it does is to declare new `req` and `path` in the scope of loop, which is new every iteration, so every closure binds to different value.

Comment: Or declare `req` and `path` as global variables! (`var req string` and `var path string` before starting to loop)

Comment: @DanielSchuette No, that doesn't work. Try yourself.

Comment: Works for me. You have to replace `:=` with `=` and re-assign a temporary variable in the loop, of course. My answer might have been to short to make that point, though. It is not really different from your solution, too.

Comment: @DanielSchuette So you just promote those assigned in `for` statement to global scope. What's the point?

Comment: That's how I usually do it, especially because it looks cleaner. But that is opinion-based, of course. I think it is easier for others to see WHY you reassign inside the for-loop if you use another variable. It's just an alternative, that's why I wrote this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be the one used here (which I thanks to the answer now understand): https://github.com/golang/blog/blob/master/rewrite.go:

`path := fileRoutes[req]` *before* `http.HandleFunc`